# error in eclipse --- java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: null

Tags: eclipse, selenium

Used *jdk 7
selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar
eclipse java indigosr1win32.*

When I run my server, by cmd:

`java - jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar 4444`

the server's stopping by itself after showing some message, and getting next prompt:

`server not working properly`.

When I run my program I got an error in eclipse:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: null`

Comment: Post the server launching snippet(code) and the entire error log.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify port number 4444 ...Selenium server by default will run on port 4444.
Write on CMD java - jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar

If you want to give port no ...Specify as 
java - jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -port 4445